# Magento redirects HTTPS sub pages to Frontpage

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, magento, magento-1.9

I have a magento shop that runs with `HTTPS` and I want to redirect all `HTTP` sub pages to the `HTTPS` version.

So e.g http://example.com/product/product1.html 
To https://example.com/product/product1.html

Right now the `HTTP` version redirects to front page - how do I change this ?

My .htaccess file:

```
SetEnvIf HTTPS On HTTPS=on
############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

#    php_value memory_limit 64M
    php_value memory_limit 256M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable magic quotes for php request vars

    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

###########################################
# turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on


############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}


RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.spotvvs.dk/$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]


</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

###########################################
## Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version

    <Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>

############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    #FileETag none


<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value memory_limit 1024M
</IfModule>


    RedirectMatch 301 /index.php/((?!admin).*) https://www.spotvvs.dk/$1
```

Comment: It is by default .htaccess file of magento, right ?

Comment: This is the default file except the last line, where redirect index.php version to root version.

Comment: Questions about how to redirect come in weekly to Stack overflow, always some incorrect .htaccess solution. People, you can set the base unsecure url and secure url to whatever it needs to be, no need to muck around with htaccess rules. The only rewrite in the htaccess should be to the index.php. Stop it with the rewrites!

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use this code once in htaccess file

```
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment



  RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.dancing-buddha.com/$1 [R,L]

  RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

  ############################################
  ## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
  RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
```

Comment: I tried added this where it already was RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}] - but it doesen't work - should I delete anything?

Comment: No need to add anything from your end.  place mine code on line number 148. Flush Magento Cache and browser cache. In case if APC cache exists then flush that once too.
Check site URL in another browser OR in browser's private mode.

Comment: Please check I updated post with the edited htaccess file, can it really be true to have two times RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]? Also now it redirects to : https://www.example.com/https://www.example.com/minilux-loftsbeslag.html

Comment: keep only one. no need to write two times same line.

Comment: Okay but the redirect ends up at: https://example.com/https://www.example.com/minilux-loftsbeslag.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78814/discussion-between-deep-kakkar-and-troels-johannesen).